# Looking for a small fix to Ambiance themed Nautilus window!

Tags: 14.04, nautilus, themes

As you should see in the snapshot, at the edges of the Nautilus window (Ambiance and Radiance themes in Ubuntu 14.04.2) on the ends of the seam between the title bar and the one below it (don't know what you exactly call them), there are a few white pixels visible where the panel rounds up.

I looked into the codes, but I didn't manage to find the fix. Can someone please help me with this?

[image: snap01]

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, I looked into the codes too (gtk-3 and unity folders in the Ambiance theme) but, at the end, the problem is related to themes associated with Ambiance (it's explained [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/light-themes-colors/+bug/1317886)). Steps to fix:

1. Kill Nautilus (ALT+F2 killall nautilus)
2. Open Unity Tweak Tool
3. Select the Ambiance theme
4. Open Nautilus again